# How to use ...CompletedEventHandler

Tags: web-services

I included Web-service to my project, it should have a method progressWorkflowAction, but I don't see this method, I just see a delegate progressWorkflowActionCompletedEventHandler and class progressWorkflowActionCompletedEventArgs. How to use it to call my method? Thanks

Comment: What sort of project? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.NET? Winforms? What type of web service - ASMX? WCF? The methods that are generated can differ depending on the project type.